# Moving ssrs ad hoc reports

Tags: reporting-services, report

We have a reporting server which has a bunch of reports and some ad hoc user reports created by users using report builder. Now we need to move all these to a different server. The new server already has some reports in it. I need to move all the reports from the older server to a folder in the new server because of this moving the database from the old server to the new server is not an option. I want to know if we have some other way to export all the reports from the older server and then deploy it to the new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ReportingService web service to programmatically interact with SSRS.  I used it once to create a basic bulk report uploader.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.aspx

Alternatively, some googling turned up this application, although I've never used it.
http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62